# how to use bullet in hydro?

Tags: ros, bullet, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a package that depends on bullet and try to compile on hydro, however I couldn't find ros-hydro-bullet nor bullet key in rosdistro/hydro/release.yaml.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64481/how-to-use-bullet-in-hydro?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bullet is now a system dependency and is registered in rosdep as such. If you look at [rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml) you can see there is a key for bullet.

Here is [the commit](https://github.com/laas/visp_tracker/commit/e7a93d69dc0ce415e57f3c02e638e92f2e1d53fa) adapting `vision_visp` to Hydro (removing the ROS dependency and detecting Bullet with pkg-config instead).

Chances are that you will probably need an equivalent commit to adapt your own software to Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0